# Adding & Executing small .net "scripts" in WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

We have a wpf app which uses a lot of configuration for say UI toolbar/buttons etc. incl. when they're enabled/disabled etc. using the ICommand where they're bound at run-time based on the function name etc.

Quite a few of these functions are really simply such as

```
bool CanExecuteThisCommandIf(MyParms p){
     return MyObject != null && MyObject.Type == MyEnum.Type3
}
```

and the definitions in the db table include

```
toolbar_id
button_id
caption 
func_name
enabled_if
button_image
tooltip_text
```

and the code that gets executed is

so there are lot of these one line functions which are executed in the context of the window/usercontrol

Now, looking for a way to include the body of this function in the config table itself rather than creating this one line function in code

From reading the details of CMS such as orchard, Umbraco etc. it seems they're creating rules in their admin screens for various actions with some minimalistic grammer which is somewhat similar to what i'm looking to do so hoping it's possible

```
Questions
a) is it possible to create these scriptlets
b) how ?
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. *However, It is not trivial unless you relax the requirements.*

Here are several ways in which to accomplish something like this:

**Option 1:**

You can approach this problem by creating (or finding an existing) pseudo-language based on tokens to describe the actions you need performed.

SharePoint does something similar, as do some frameworks that allow dynamic code to be generated from config files.

Basically, you use XML or any pseudo-language of choice to define the behaviors, parameters, and conditions for your methods. You can even include actual C# code in there if you wish.

You can then generate dynamic assembly on the fly and using reflection invoke the method on your toolbar.

Look at these namespaces for more info:

```
System.CodeDom.Compiler 
System.Reflection.Emit
```

The System.Reflection.Emit namespace has an ILGenerator class which you can use to create IL instructions as part of dynamically generated types.

*This is probably more involved than it's worth for this small task.*

**Option 2:**

Another approach is to use a plug-in architecture and dynamically load DLL's with your specific toolbar/component related methods (based on some interface so you can execute what you need easily without lots of hard coding, like a `Command pattern`, and depending on the configuration you load the appropriate assembly and execute it's logic to configure your component.

*This is still probably more involved than you want to deal with for the task at hand.*

**Option 3:**

Probably the easiest to implement and I think makes the most sense for a small project.

You can include all of the methods you need in a common assembly and have it referenced all the time. Then use configurations to determine which methods need to be called or executed depending on which components you are loading at run-time. This circumvents the need for complex over-engineering and accomplishes the same task.

The downside of Option 3 is that you must recompile your project any time a new component is added or configured. Since you are not REALLY trying to create a dynamic, extensible application, and just looking to handle some configuration of UI components, this option still makes sense because if you were to define new components that can be configured (a new menu or an additional widget), it stands to reason you'd be recompiling your project at that time anyway.